# Oracle empty conditions to check the ' ' condition

Tags: sql, oracle, null

How do I compare a `VARCHAR2` variable, which is an empty value?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: That is not always the case. SQL Server does make a distinction between '' and NULL. Oracle (which is what the OP asked), however, does not.

Answer (score 48):

Oracle doesn't differentiate between empty strings and NULL. To check if a variable is an empty string, use the `IS NULL` syntax.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this as Oracle themselves do not recommend it.  

> Oracle Database currently treats a character value with a length of zero as null. However, this may not continue to be true in future releases, and Oracle recommends that you do not treat empty strings the same as nulls.  
  
Source: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-B0BA4751-9D88-426A-84AD-BCDBD5584071

Answer (score 12):

You could use either of these:

```
IF v_test IS NULL
THEN
   -- Business Logic
```

or

```
IF NVL(v_test, 'NULL') = 'NULL'
THEN
   -- Business Logic
```

Your question does say "compare" a VARCHAR variable which is null so if you are comparing it to another variable then:

```
IF (v_test1 IS NULL and v_test2 IS NULL)
THEN
   -- Business Logic
```

That would check if they are both null.

Hope it helps...